# using cdn in html is not loading a page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use `makerjs` on my javascript with using cdn which is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/makerjs@0/target/js/browser.maker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bezier-js@2/bezier.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@0/dist/opentype.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I putted this code on my `index.html` code, and I have nothing on my web page.

However, when I use with codepen with only this code bellow,

```
<script src="http://maker.js.org/target/js/browser.maker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/bezier.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://opentype.js.org/dist/opentype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

has no problem with rendering a page.
But if I use the first one with `vscode`, it is not rendering anything.

The `index.js` file is like this.

```
var makerjs = require('makerjs');

var line = { 
  type: 'line', 
  origin: [0, 0], 
  end: [50, 50] 
 };

var svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(line);

document.write(svg);
```

What is the problem with not rendering the page with cdn adress?

Comment: try putting cdn's under  `<head>` tag and try, just to make sure that needed js files are loaded before functions are called for desired output

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your JS around an on load function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: Happy to help :)